# Упростить код [PHP]

Tags: php

Я новичок в мире программирования. Мне нужна более основополагающая логика в решении задач.
Задача: сгенерировать стих. Есть 5 массивов из их нужно создать один общий, и уже из него выбирать элементы циклом.

Massive:

```
$word1 = array('Чудесных', 'Суровых', 'Занятных', 'Внезапных');
$word2 = array('слов', 'зим', 'глаз', 'дней', 'лет', 'мир', 'взор');
$word3 = array('прикосновений', 'поползновений', 'судьбы явлений', 'сухие листья', 'морщины смерти', 'долины края', 'замены нету', 'сухая юность', 'навек исчезнув');
$word4 = array('обретаю', 'понимаю', 'начертаю', 'закрываю', 'оставляю', 'вынимаю', 'умираю', 'замерзаю', 'выделяю' );
$word5 = array('очертания', 'безысходность',  'начертанья', 'смысл жизни', 'вирус смерти', 'радость мира');
```

Добавление массивов в один общий.

```
$allArray = array($word1, $word2, $word3, $word4, $word5);
```

Сам цикл.

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 1; $i++) {
   $random = array_rand($allArray[0]);
   $random1 = array_rand($allArray[1]);
   $random2 = array_rand($allArray[2]);
   $random3 = array_rand($allArray[3]);
   $random4 = array_rand($allArray[4]);
  
   echo $allArray[0][$random] . " " . $allArray[1][$random1] . " " . $allArray[2][$random2] . "<br>";
} 

echo "Я " . $allArray[3][$random3] . " " . $allArray[3][$random4];
```

В данном решении я определяю генератор случайного числа у массива. Затем я беру по отдельности элементы массива и вместо индекса добавляю получившиеся случайное число. 
Данное решение работает, но *очень много кода*.

**По итогу должна получится такая структура**

> слово1 слово2 слово3 
> слово1 слово2 слово3 
> Я слово4 слово5

Как правильно упростить это решение, хотелось бы узнать в развернутом ответе. Спасибо.

Comment: вы все 5 масивов сложили в один чтобы код усложнить, или зачем?

Comment: Чтобы были все массивы в одной переменной. Вроде бы логично. Но возможно это не правильно на самом деле, в любом случае жду Вашего предложения :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

сведя все в один массив вы только усложнили код, внеся в него индексы.

заведите функцию с 5 параметрами по числу массивов.

```
function write($w1, $w2, $w3, $w4, $w5){
}
```

определите функцию, которая будет возвращать случайный элемент. Если нужно чтобы элементы не повторялись, то соответственно надо их удалять. В таком случае проще всего воспользоваться `shuffle + array_shift`:

```
$rand = function(&$arr){ 
            shuffle($arr); return array_shift($arr); 
        };
```

а если с повторами то просто `return $arr[array_rand($arr)];`

Далее просто составьте строки своего стиха:

```
$line1 = implode(' ', [$rand($w1), $rand($w2), $rand($w3)]);
```

В общем виде все будет выглядеть так.

```
function write($w1, $w2, $w3, $w4, $w5){
    $rand = function(&$arr){ 
                shuffle($arr); return array_shift($arr); 
            };                       
    
    $line1 = implode(' ', [$rand($w1), $rand($w2), $rand($w3)]);
    $line2 = implode(' ', [$rand($w1), $rand($w2), $rand($w3)]);
    $line3 = implode(' ', ["Я",        $rand($w4), $rand($w5)]);
    
    return "$line1\n$line2\n$line3";
}
```

чем проще и читабельней код тем лучше. в нем сложнее допустить ошибку и легче понять. Индексы и циклы  в вашем решении делают его запутанным.

Answer (score -1):

```
$rw1=count($word1);
$rw2=count($word2);
$rw3=count($word3);
$rw4=count($word4);
$rw5=count($word5);

//без цикла
$set1=rand(0, $rw1-1);
$set2=rand(0, $rw2-1);
$set3=rand(0, $rw3-1);
$set4=rand(0, $rw4-1);
$set5=rand(0, $rw5-1);

$text=$word1[$set1].' ,'.$word2[$set2].' ,'.$word3[$set3].' ,'.$word4[$set4].' ,'.$word5[$set5];
print_r($text);
//С циклом, мсеньше кода.
for ($i=1; $i <=5 ; $i++) { 
    
    ${'rw' . $i}=count(${'word' . $i});
    
    ${'set' . $i}=rand(0, ${'rw' . $i}-1);
    
    $summ[]= ${'word' . $i}[${'set' . $i}];
    
    }
    echo "<br>";
    $comma_separated = implode(" ", $summ);
    print_r($comma_separated);
    echo "<br>";
```

Comment: Совершенный ужас. У автора хотя бы понятно что происходит. А что здесь происходит - непонятно никому.

Comment: онж сказал сократить код